# Filling a string and showing it in a gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a gridview where I gather stuff from a SQL server. All columns are ok, except for the one that shows all the possible options.

Stored Procedure works just fine and it gives a single column called "tipoId" with the array of desired values, so no problem there.

Now, for the displaying part. All columns work just fine, except for this one.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" SortExpression="">
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
     <ItemTemplate><%# GetOpciones(Eval("Username").ToString())% </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And this is the part where I fill the string for that specific part.

```
public string GetOpciones(string username)
{
      ASF.Raffle.BO.Staff usr = new ASF.Raffle.BO.Staff();
      ASF.Raffle.Entity.Staff u = usr.GetByUsername(username);
      string salida = usr.getAllOptions("bravoje");
      return usr.getAllOptions(u.Username);
}

public string getAllOptions(string usr)
{
    string result="";
    //SQL Command para llamar el stored procedure
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("dbo.[Equipos_GetOptionsByUserName]", base.Db);
    //parametros del store procedure
    SqlParameter spSearch = new SqlParameter("@usr", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    spSearch.Value = usr;
    comando.Parameters.Add(spSearch);
    //Ejecuta consulta
    DataTable dtItem = base.Execute(comando);
    //Transforma el Datatable en una lista de proyectos.
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtItem.Rows)
        result += dr.ToString() + "<br>";
     return result;
 }
```

To avoid all human errors, I even typed manually a user I know exists and I tested the stored procedure and it does return the results with that specific value (a list of them).

Thanks,
EB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies on this line: `result += dr.ToString() + "<br>";`.  You are not accessing each column in the row (or any columns).  Calling `ToString()` on the row will just return it's type.

You can access each column by index using `dr[0], dr[1], ...`.  For example:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtItem.Rows)
   result += $"{dr[0]} <br>";
```

Or by column name `dr["tipold"], dr["col2"], ...`. Example:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtItem.Rows)
    result += string.Format("{0}<br>", dr["tipold"]);
```